# How do i calculate the duration of a segment of music with a changing tempo?

Tags: theory, tempo

I'm writing some music software that allows you to dynamically set the tempo. I'm having trouble calculating the duration of a section if the tempo is gradually increasing or decreasing. For example, if the piece starts on 100bpm and gradually increases to 200bpm by the 10th measure (drastic increase just for ease of numbers), all my calculations seem to be off. I've tried using the distance (in beats) with the change in tempo to figure out the acceleration of the tempo and get the time from that, but that still isn't working. I know it isn't working because I can let it play through the 10 measures and see that its off (sometimes be an entire second). I have confirmed the correct value in other software as well.

Comment: Your tempo is in beats per minute, but the time taken comes from the number of minutes per beat. If your bpm goes up as 100, 110, 120, .., 200 the times for each bar will be *approximately* 1/105, 1/115, .. , 1/195, so these will be the numbers to add. If you need better approximations for the duration of each interval please say so.

Comment: Can you specify how your program ‘gradually increases tempo’. What formula do you use? Is it done stepwise (every bar or beat) or smooth (where a 128th note would be slightly shorter than the previous 128th note?)

Comment: Heck, even if your program "gradually increases tempo" smoothly, what's the smooth curve like? Does the rate of tempo change accelerate, decelerate, do both, or stay the same throughout? (I personally like tempo curves that accelerate the rate of tempo change as they go along.)

Comment: It works in a stepwise fashion. I calculate the difference in tempo and increase/decrease the tempo every 512th note(or every few depending on the rate of change) to get to the desired tempo by the end of the section. You can somewhat simulate an acceleration curse. The program allows you to add a point to the track with the vertical axis mapping the tempo and the horizontal axis plotting the beats. So you could plot something close to an acceleration curve.

Answer (score 3):

#### The simple answer

Assume that the tempo always changes at a constant rate. In that case, it's sufficient to calculate the average tempo and multiply that by the number of beats involved. However, tempo in this scenario must be given in minutes per beat (i.e., how long does a single beat last) rather than beats per minute. MPB is just the inverse of BPM. For example, 30 BPM = 1/30 MPB; in other words at 30 BPM each beat lasts 2 seconds, which is clearly also the case for 1/30 MPB.

**Example**

Suppose a piece is in 4/4 time, and there is a tempo increase from 100bpm to 200bpm over the course of 10 measures, which is to say, 40 beats. In other words, at the beginning of the 10 measures each beat lasts .01 minutes (i.e., .01mpb), and at the end of the 10 measures each beat lasts .005 minutes (i.e., .005mpb). Then the average speed is .0075mpb. Over the span of 40 beats, this gives a total time of .3 minutes, or 18 seconds.

---

#### The real answer

1. Since we're trying to calculate total time, we need to know the minutes per beat (mpb), rather than beats per minute (bpm). MPB times the number of beats elapsed gives the amount of time elapsed.
2. Let f(*x*) be the MPB at beat *x*. That is, f(*x*) = how long a beat takes after *x* beats have gone by. f(*x*), therefore, represents beat-speed at a certain time.
3. Therefore, the total time required to change from one beat-speed to another over *n* beats is calculated by the integral of f(*x*) over the interval [0, *n*].

**Example**

Suppose a piece is in 4/4 time, and there is a tempo increase from 100bpm to 200bpm over the course of 10 measures, which is to say, 40 beats. In other words, at the beginning of the 10 measures each beat lasts .01 minutes (i.e., .01mpb), and at the end of the 10 measures each beat lasts .005 minutes (i.e., .005mpb). Assume the rate of change in tempo is constant. Then to calculate the tempo (in MPB) at a given beat, we have f(*x*) = .01 - .005(*x*/40) = .01 - .000125*x*. Integration over the interval [0, 40] gives .3 minutes (i.e., 18 seconds). ([This can be verified at integral-calculator.com](https://www.integral-calculator.com/).)

This is confirmed by "the simple answer" above, which is also based on the assumption of a constant rate of tempo change.

Comment: I've often wondered whether tempo step changes should be *logarithmic* like pitch changes, so to double the speed from 100 to 200 bpm in 12 steps, at each step you'd multiply the existing tempo by by 12th root of 2 rather than just adding 8.33 bpm.

Comment: @BrianTHOMAS Interesting. Let's see ... in that case, f(x) = .01 - .005(2^[x/12]). With an assist from [integral-calclator.com](https://www.integral-calculator.com/), the total time for the accelerando would be approximately 0.033 minutes, or nearly 2 seconds. For comparison with the above answer, a 40-beat change would be .01 - .005(2^[x/40]) and take about 0.11 minutes, or 6.6 seconds.

Comment: @BrianThomas - I've often been satisfied with roughly *arithmetic* tempo step changes (e.g. 144 bpm -> 138 bpm -> 130 bpm -> 120 bpm - note that the differences between bpms are 6 bpm -> 8 bpm -> 10 bpm).

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. This has been blocking me for quite a while. I never even thought to invert it to MPB.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the purpose of the software you are developping, specifically real-time processing or not, my hint may apply to you or rather not. After all, you might be interested nevertheless.

### A tick and its duration

If it is not bound to real-time constraints (offline synthesis), i.e. if you know beforehand how long the notes actually are, you can find the amount of the closest distance between all musically relevant events, i.e. note offsets and lengths/releases in a measure, in beats or floating-point shares of a beat.

That minimal distance, dividing the length of a measure in beats, and the resulting quotient again ceiled to the next integer, is the number of ticks in that measure to which you need to assign a length in milliseconds each. The total length of a measure = 60 seconds / how many bpm * beats per measure, needs to be divided by that number, to get the constant duration of a tick. This is the basic understanding.

If you want to get further or not, the earlier you abstract your calculations from bpm, breaking the tempo down into tick durations as shown above, the more flexible you can get to realize a multitude of rhythmic conventions in whatever music style you can think of, without necessarily giving a mechanical feel to your music. You just separate the logical offset and duration of a note, measured in beats and sub-beats, eighths or alike, from the actual durations in seconds, the interface factor between both being the duration of the tick.

Once you are able to calculate an array of tick durations in a measure, you have achieved an higher-order concept of tempo. So, you could even make the tick durations oscillate and modulate in a non-contiguous, but circularly recurring manner to realize swing- and shuffle-like patterns and other elaborate variations of rhythm.

After all, I recommend you think rather in seconds than in minutes because sound processing refers to sampling rate based on the second. In a 4/4 measure with 120bpm, here specifically fourths per minute, you need to calculate 60/120 = 0.5s a tick. Sure, if you have eighth notes (rests) in a measure, you would rather go with 0.25s for each of 8 ticks in the measure. Or 0.03125s per tick if you have got sixty-fourths therein and so forth.

What you actually must do due to the nature of floating point numbers, is capping the closest distance between musical events that your program can resolve, evening out all distances below. Otherwise you might run out of memory as there can occur tiny inaccuracies in calculation, yielding many tiny ticks in a measure that can hardly be mapped to distinct samples at a reasonable sampling rate.

### Linear tempo changes

A linear change of the tempo can be realized tick-wise simply by weighted averages of start tempo (say 120bpm) and end tempo of a bar (say 135bpm) using evenly increasing weights from 1.0 to 0.0 for the former and 0.0 to 1.0 for the latter. First, calculate from the tempo indications the tick durations as shown. Then, depending on where the note starts and ends in terms of beats or shares of a beat, you sum the durations of the respective ticks in the array. The border ticks might need a linearly proportional cut-off from the start and the end (that is, shares of them ticks) to restore accuracy again that you lost by ceiling to and calculating with integers.

Having read other answers and comments to the question: Integrals serve you well if you, provided you are not a mathematician, want to stick with linear changes. If you want to go even further, you need to be one, or you need to consider to sum ticks, precalculated time-slices indeed. I guess noone's ear will ever perceive that border ticks have been proportionally cut off as a means of interpolation.

### Polynomial gradients

If you are not content with just linear changes, because I guess they could provoke rather mechanical feelings in listeners of your music, you might also consider n-degree polynomials (bézier curves, free-form design) of which you can then set the co-efficient of every degree. This is what I have tried in my own "text-defined sound and music modelling from scratch" software project.

So, in a measure where the shortest occuring musically relevant duration is a sixty-fourth, by tracing in the polynomial gradient G(t) at every step for both the x- and y-dimension, that is at t=0.0, 1/64, 2/64, ..., 64/64=1.0, you calculate a sequence of 64 tick lengths (@y=1.00 == 120bpm):

[image: Example graph of a tempo gradient from 120bpm over 135bpm to 130bpm]

So, every note and offset of consecutive notes, that cover the 40th tick must get these 60,000ms per minute / (16 ticks per beat * minimum 120bpm * ticks[39]=1.0888 times the minimum value) = 28.7ms summed into its total length. This calculation presumes that a beat is a fourth or 16 sixty-fourths.

(To my own notes to reconstruct graph: `r -S "64:120;3,135;5,130"`)